# autoslide javascript slider not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've made a slider using Javascript & HTML but I have a problem with it. The autoslide is working but the dots aren't changing it stays stuck on the first one and the other problem is that when we click on one of the arrow, the slider speeds up. Any ideas of what could be wrong here?

here's my code :

```js
  var slideIndex = 1;

  showImage(slideIndex);

  function plusIndex(n) {
    showImage(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide(n){
    showImage(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showImage(n) {
    var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");

    if (n > slide.length) {slideIndex = 1};
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slide.length};

    for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
      slide[i].style.display = "none";
    };
    slide[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    };

    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";

 autoslide();
    function autoslide(){
      var i;
      var slide= document.getElementsByClassName("slides")
      for (var i=0;  i<slide.length;i++) {
        slide[i].style.display= "none";
      }
      if (slideIndex> slide.length) {slideIndex=1}
      slide[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      slideIndex++;
      setTimeout(autoslide,2000);
    }
}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: verdana,sans-serif;
}

h1 {
      text-align: center;
}

.slideshow-container {
      width: 800px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
}

.slides {
      display: none;
}

img {
      width: 100%;
}

.number {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      color: #f2f2f2;
}

.text {
      text-align: center;
      font size: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      bottom: 20px;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-weight: bold;
}

.prev, .next {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 10px 10px ;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      cursor: pointer;
}

.next {
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
      right: 0;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.dots {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      background: gray;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
}

.fade {
      animation-name: fade;
      animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
      from{opacity: 0.4}
      to{opacity: 1;}
}

.active, .dots:hover {
      background: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Slidder Show</title>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <h1>Les 7 merveilles du Monde</h1>

</head>
<body>

  <!--Container Slide Show-->
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="slides fade">
      <div class="number">1 / 7</div>
      <div><img src="https://www.wallpapertip.com/wmimgs/44-447835_delhi-ke-wallpaper-38-group-wallpapers-taj-mahal.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">Le Taj Mahal</div>
    </div>

    <div class="slides fade">
      <div class="number">2 / 7</div>
      <div><img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp1885729.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">Le Chichen Itza</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusIndex(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusIndex(+1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
  <br/>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

.......................................
.......................................

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import your js script to Html, I had tried it on my own and it's working!

Just put it before body closing tag like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scriptJs.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I still have the same problem. If you rune my snippet code, you'll see what I'm talking about, the dots aren't moving and once you click one or 2 twimes on one of the arrow, the slider just speeds up